# Rows Selected in SQL Results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a simple query to group by certain columns. The file I am using has 99,000 rows. After the query is executed it says their is only 72,979 rows. Also, throughout the results grid (see row 47 in Results Screenshot) it displays an amount of rows selected. Is my query omitting those rows? If so how can I include them?

Thank you.

```
use [OMNI Digital]

select GL_PERI, EVENT, EVT_PRICE, TRANS_AMT, TRAFFIC_PROG, CONTRACT, 
EVENT_DESC, DELIV, FMT, BUY_OR_CREDIT, Count(ACCOUNT)

from Duplicate_2013006

group by GL_PERI, EVENT, EVT_PRICE, TRANS_AMT, TRAFFIC_PROG, 
CONTRACT, EVENT_DESC, DELIV, FMT, BUY_OR_CREDIT
```

Results Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Why is ACCOUNT included in the GROUP BY clause? Also, DATE_BILLED and DATE_INGEST are not on your SELECT?

Comment: Avoid using two database tag because it is different. It's either mysql or sql

Comment: there are only 72,979 rows because of the GROUP BY clause.  GROUP BY will consolidate/group any exact same rows and only return 1 result per distinct values of the columns you specify in the GROUP BY.  Change up the columns and see what happens

Comment: Must better to include some sample data and expected result than to present a query.

Comment: i agree to @matt it is because of `group by` clause. Your query returns all counts of group by fields. that is why you got a result of lower than you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT(1) over(partition by.....) This will prevent Rollup associated with group by